# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{exp(r)}{r^n}=\infty$ from the definition

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{exp(r)}{r^n}=\infty$ from the definition.

The definition in my text says: 
For a sequence $(S_n)$, we write $limS_n=\infty$ provided for each $M>0$ there is a number N such that $n>N$ implies that $S_n>M$.

So I need to consider an arbitrary $M>0$ and show that there exists $N$ [which will depend on $M$] such that $n>M$ implies $\frac{exp(r)}{r^n}>M$

To see how big N must be we normally solve for n in the inequality.

So far I have only had to do limit definitions for equalities and inequalities that have just one variable but in this case there is an $r$ and $n$ and even if I knew which one to solve for (I think $r$ in this case) I'm not sure how to isolate it since the $r$ is in both the numerator and denominator.

So my question is how can I choose my $n>M$ for this case?

Note: I know how to show the limit is infinite using limits and l'Hopital's rule but I'm not allowed to use this as my formal proof I must use the definition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: did you mean $exp(n)$? if not $exp(r)$ is just a constant

Comment: Try taking the logarithm.

Comment: I meant $exp(r)$, so if $exp(r)$is just a constant do i just solve for $r$ in the denominator to get $r>\sqrt[n]\frac{exp(r)}{M}$?@Sorfosh

Comment: I don't see how taking the logarithm helps me find the $n>M$ could you elaborate I would really appreciate it. Thanks,@saulspatz

Comment: @jack is $|r|<1$?

Comment: $r>0$ but I don't see what you hinting to I'm not sure how to tell if $r<1$ or what it means if it is. $r^n$ in this question is supposed to represent a polynomial@Sorfosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve for n:
$$\frac{e^r}{r^n} = \frac{e^r}{e^{(\ln{(r^n)})}} =  \frac{e^r}{e^{(n \cdot\ln{r})}} = e^r\cdot e^{n\cdot(-\ln{r})}$$
If you want a tight bound you can solve the following inequality for n: $$e^r\cdot e^{n\cdot(-\ln{r})} > M$$
$$e^{n\cdot(-\ln{r})} > \frac{M}{e^r}$$
$$n \cdot (-\ln{r}) > \ln{\left(\frac{M}{e^r}\right)}$$
$$n > \frac{\ln{\left(\frac{M}{\exp{(r)}}\right)}}{-\ln{r}}$$
$$n > \frac{\ln{\left(\frac{M}{\exp{(r)}}\right)}}{\ln{\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)}}$$
$$n > \ln{\left(\frac{M}{e^r}-\frac{1}{r}\right)}$$